# Python and sorting data based on lowest int value

Tags: python

I have a large set of data (list of tuples) that is pretty much repeated. I am trying to only identify the employees with the lowset scores.

Example, the 'Employer 1' has 'John Smith' and 'Allan Smith'. These are managers and the int value represents their weight/score. I want to select only the rows with the lower values for each employer. As you can see 'employer 3' only has one entry with a weight of 1. So no selection is required as its the lowset value for that employer.

```
    dataset = [
    ('Employer 1', 'Video Editor', '2018-05-08 10:22:31', 'Dataset1', 'John Smith', '2'),
    ('Employer 1', 'Video Editor', '2018-05-08 10:22:31', 'Dataset2', 'Allan Smith', '1'),
    ('Employer 1', 'Video Editor', '2018-05-08 10:22:31', 'Dataset3', 'John Smith', '2'),
    ('Employer 1', 'Video Editor', '2018-05-08 10:22:31', 'Dataset2', 'Allan Smith', '1'),
    ('Employer 1', 'Video Editor', '2018-05-08 10:22:31', 'Dataset1', 'John Smith', '2'),
    ('Employer 1', 'Video Editor', '2018-05-08 10:22:31',  'Dataset3', 'Allan Smith', '1'),
    ('Employer 2', 'Cook', '2018-05-08 10:22:31',  'Dataset1', 'james bond', '3'),
    ('Employer 2', 'Cook', '2018-05-08 10:22:31',  'Dataset1', 'james bond', '3'),
    ('Employer 2', 'Cook', '2018-05-08 10:22:31',  'Dataset1', 'james brown', '1'),
    ('Employer 2', 'Cook', '2018-05-08 10:22:31',  'Dataset1', 'james brown', '1'),
    ('Employer 3', 'Cook', '2018-05-08 10:22:31',  'Dataset1', 'james brown', '1'),
    ('Employer 3', 'Cook', '2018-05-08 10:22:31',  'Dataset1', 'james brown', '1')]
```

Comment: What did you do so far ? Take a look at `groupby` then `sorted` and then take the first element.

Comment: When you say "lower values" do you mean *lowest value* for each employer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` with `min`:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for a, *b in dataset:
  d[a].append(b)

results = {a:min(b, key=lambda x:int(x[-1])) for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'Employer 1': ['Video Editor', '2018-05-08 10:22:31', 'Dataset2', 'Allan Smith', '1'], 'Employer 2': ['Cook', '2018-05-08 10:22:31', 'Dataset1', 'james brown', '1'], 'Employer 3': ['Cook', '2018-05-08 10:22:31', 'Dataset1', 'james brown', '1']}
```

Note that the above syntax (unpacking) only works in Python3. However, below is a very similar solution for Python2:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in dataset:
  d[i[0]].append(i[1:])

results = {a:min(b, key=lambda x:int(x[-1])) for a, b in d.items()}
```

Comment: Since you have a star assignment, Python 3 only.

Comment: This and the answer by @dawg solve the problem I was facing, could you please break down the answer to explain what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, you are looking for:

1. The min from each group;
2. A list of each employee in the group with that min value.

This groupby loop does that:

```
from itertools import groupby

for k,g in groupby(sorted(dataset), key=lambda t: t[0]):
    g=list(g)
    low=min(g, key=lambda t: int(t[-1]))[-1]
    print k, list({t for t in g if t[-1]==low})
```

Prints:

```
Employer 1 [('Employer 1', 'Video Editor', '2018-05-08 10:22:31', 'Dataset2', 'Allan Smith', '1'), ('Employer 1', 'Video Editor', '2018-05-08 10:22:31', 'Dataset3', 'Allan Smith', '1')]
Employer 2 [('Employer 2', 'Cook', '2018-05-08 10:22:31', 'Dataset1', 'james brown', '1')]
Employer 3 [('Employer 3', 'Cook', '2018-05-08 10:22:31', 'Dataset1', 'james brown', '1')]
```

The set comprehension is only required if you actually have dup tuples in the groups...

Comment: yes this is correct, I want each iteration of the Employer with the lowest weight score. This and the answer above it are correct. Could you break down the for loop to explain whats its doing.